# PHP Escape character

Tags: php, stringescapeutils

I'm using PHP environment and I have a problem in displaying data on form of escape characters.

example:

how could i display a double quote `"` if my string data is `\"`

same with, how could i display a backslash `\` if my string data is `\\`

Comment: When displaying data on form, you need *HTML* escaping, not PHP

Comment: Im not displaying data on HTML, I raise this question for export to excel purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `\` characters that are used as an escape characters, use the `stripslashes` function.

```
david@raston ~ $ cat tmp/test.php
<?php

$raw = 'double slash \\\\ escaped quote \"';
print $raw;
print "\n";
print stripslashes($raw);
?>

david@raston ~ $ php tmp/test.php
double slash \\ escaped quote \"
double slash \ escaped quote "
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else has covered it and this is all [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) but for the sake of completeness I'd also suggest taking a look at the `heredoc` notation which can be useful when your data is changing through several contexts (eg. PHP -> HTML/JS -> JS-Regex)

```
<?php
echo <<<__EOF
It's not great for PHP indentation but often helps readability \ " ' `
__EOF;
```